# Difference of using php artisan serve and not using it

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

What is the difference of using `php artisan serve` and by just using `localhost/myproject/public`?

Some of my code is not working when I'm just using the `localhost/myproject/public`, but when using `php artisan serve` all works just fine. Why is that?

Comment: You need to elaborate further on what exactly is working and what not.

Comment: I guess you mean doubleclicking index.php? Yeah you need a PHP interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

main difference is **who have the role to be the web server ?** Means : who have the role to intercept HTTP request and provide it to PHP compiler.

With traditional web server (apache, nginx ...)

- Web service will catch request, then ask php to do traitment with.

With PHP server  `php artisan serve` php himself have role to manage this step. that means, if error happen on your process, this will shutdown your server. Apache will not be affected by this error, so rest of application will be still available.

Now about differente way to ask php to execute some code :

- For Apache you can have `php-mod`, who are an extension of Apache or `php-fpm` (describe bellow)
- For Nginx or other WebService, you have `php-fpm` or `php-fastcgi`, both are way (by TCP or Unix Socket) of communcation between your web service instance (processus) and php instance (processus).
- `php-cli` who are the php instance spawn when you do `php something` on your terminal

For each approch you have differente `php.ini` and `php extension` to download / activate.

That means, for exemple, if you need to use `Imagick` library by command line tool (`php-cli`) and from your web server (`php-mod` on Apache) you have to download and activate this library on both setup.